# Refresh token not changing QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK OAuth 2.0

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

As per sdk documentation.
https://intuit.github.io/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK/authorization.html

"That is what refresh token used for. It is used to request a new access token after access token expired, so you can still access to the QBO company after an hour. Just remember, whenever you make a refreshToken API call, always STORE THE LATEST REFRESH TOKEN value in your session or database"

This is the case: So my access token is expired I need to get a new one I'll run the code below.

```
$loginHelper = new OAuth2LoginHelper($this->clientID, $this->clientSecret);
$token = $loginHelper->refreshAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($this->refreshToken);
```

Then the token variable in code above will give me the new access token using this code.

```
$token->getAccessToken();
```

It was successful I have the new access token now.

However, seems refresh token is not changing quickbooks said "STORE THE LATEST REFRESH TOKEN" but the $token obj returns are the same.

My refresh token use to request new access token is:

```
string(50) "Q011532218006WxAY7UnIdulGDJAcgnaoTi7pIkHVaaQld9Me3"
```

then the return of my request:

```
QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\OAuth\OAuth2\OAuth2AccessToken Object
    (
        [accessTokenKey:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\OAuth\OAuth2\OAuth2AccessToken:private] => eyJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2IiwiYWxnIjoiZGlyIn0..llxj6kOGCzFiqBShGPUtbg.rNbEdMvhD0iER3z4IwB-azYbbk9givKxtaiDh7Uch8HbmZLkF7-xckpgiMDk8V5lYwYOCfP1EaPFa0iJlpbNPZdT7RBfPIkEqotTVfP0UNPwC13a37PpYHOvg_Sxbp_5GuOvdIa1RVskn4tY_FIOaCVnTaxuDF4MWNKOxsitHEoYxzVVcdqigTWri9yfIA6ZqO2vTAc92iTsa30L9jYcFeEdaNVaPt7zyM-y_FzY2W72uq8fyYjpv-fmvWMwv94pCJ6VoV82rM7OmLh5sOWORKfcZJ0xDLMrKddUPnA0GVl3mb3E6D-JyQ2-N2AYNW553nryI9f9iuoAqv7f6bXhzmaO-ByN0xtDEt9E48CFN-tyA_qShtwmEUajhsq0XFrUZgR0rtEq2kSvj79v3-sX1P7qCjPPrGK2q12VQ24DbVWnDYDZslYh9nyJGtiZgXu-GWFNKhfaXI76U_ASC2yefrcWu6ioIdDrn8j75B9AZgg3GpBqkT7H2qHWGqieeuJmcuFVoYIJUiztZNrDWYvmCJv_w2KlG911GHqLO7K7AznzpiSdIWwGXVBSxYRBbCVQTFJge1SYkXYOWj1OP9aFttpxRNX_ctiAiqV5IA9JBs_T3H4w6mGYRt4NpXZCMn3Yguwc1LekmCn0r83taHjvOT0_l78c1zv2nWC_ADKgdd1lPLMzQHiNWnHCDIBrRYm0.h0WaCjevbfdig0G-zQM9eA
        [tokenType:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\OAuth\OAuth2\OAuth2AccessToken:private] => bearer
        [refresh_token:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\OAuth\OAuth2\OAuth2AccessToken:private] => Q011532218006WxAY7UnIdulGDJAcgnaoTi7pIkHVaaQld9Me3
        [accessTokenExpiresAt:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\OAuth\OAuth2\OAuth2AccessToken:private] => 1523499723
        [refreshTokenExpiresAt:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\OAuth\OAuth2\OAuth2AccessToken:private] => 1532218006
        [accessTokenValidationPeriod:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\OAuth\OAuth2\OAuth2AccessToken:private] => 3600
        [refreshTokenValidationPeriod:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\OAuth\OAuth2\OAuth2AccessToken:private] => 8721883
        [clientID:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\OAuth\OAuth2\OAuth2AccessToken:private] => Q032lsDMTnotxhcOudLOpyfYuDXfB9xEMWpMRpvFIwW1VV1eyQ
        [clientSecret:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\OAuth\OAuth2\OAuth2AccessToken:private] => Ml3Id7ZgeVNzAbxecHwwwzrBmuKeQXw7kljlwT84
        [realmID:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\OAuth\OAuth2\OAuth2AccessToken:private] => 
        [baseURL:QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\OAuth\OAuth2\OAuth2AccessToken:private] => 
    )
```

Comment: Possible to share your full PHP SDK code that you are using to generate new access tokens using refresh token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per quickbooks developer, "The previous refresh token expires after 24 hours after you create a new one. So you would get the same refresh token from the time you refresh untill the next 24 hours."

Read more: [Click Here](https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D50f00005MzpES/refresh-token-not-changing-quickbooksv3phpsdk-oauth-20?t=1523919964410)